# Can't fill form wihtout name with mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to fill a form with mechanize, the form has no `name` or `id`.

This is my code:

```
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new
page = a.get("http://www.lauradesmaison.book.fr/contact/")
form = page.form()
form['nom'] = "Name"
form['societe'] = "Society"
form['email'] = "user@mail.com"
form['tel'] = "0123456789"
form['texte'] = "My message"
button = form.button_with(:name => "submit-contact")
page = a.submit(form, button)

puts "Message has been sent."
```

But I have an `undefined method`[]`=' for nil:NilClass` error line 6.

I tried with `form = page.forms[0]` but same error.
Any idea?

Comment: It means there's no form on that page.

Comment: But there is one form `<form action="/contact/" method="post">`, why Mechanize doesn't detect it?

Comment: If you look closely at the page source you'll see that there's not really a form there.